# How can I make a blocking Java thread waiting for Tomcat interuptable

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I have embedded Tomcat inside a JavaFX application. I need Tomcat to run for the duration of my application lifespan.

`Thread.stop()` is deprecated, so I'm trying to use another method, but this always gives me an exception

```
"Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" on the line 74: tomcat.wait(500);.

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at webappgen.TomcatThread.run(WebServer.java:74)
        at webappgen.WebServer.Start(WebServer.java:22)
        at webappgen.Project.StartWebServer(Project.java:31)
        at webappgen.FXMLDocumentController.handleNewProjectAction(FXMLDocumentController.java:81)
        ... 56 more
```

Here is what I'm trying:

```
package webappgen;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;


public class WebServer {

    TomcatThread thread;

    public WebServer(){

    }

    public void Start(String dir){

        thread = new TomcatThread(dir);
        thread.run();

    }

    public void Stop(){
        synchronized(TomcatThread.obj){
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}


class TomcatThread extends Thread {
    public static final Object obj = new Object();
    private String dir;
    private volatile boolean stopServer = false;

    public void StopServer(boolean stop){
        this.stopServer = stop;
    }
    public TomcatThread(String dir){
        this.dir = dir;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String webappDirLocation = dir;
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        String webPort = "8083";
        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

        try {
            tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (ServletException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

        try {
            tomcat.start();
        } catch (LifecycleException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        synchronized(TomcatThread.obj){
            while(!stopServer){

                try {
                     tomcat.wait(500);

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(TomcatThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        }
        try {
            tomcat.getServer().stop();
            tomcat.getServer().destroy();
        } catch (LifecycleException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TomcatThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: you're getting the exception because what you're waiting on isn't the same as what you're synchronizing on.

Comment: @NathanHughes that was it, combined with removing the while loop and just using wait().

Comment: on removing the while loop: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [Thread.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) to wait for the TomcatThread to die after the thread has started;